# How to create a pool of threads in python where i can have fixed number of threads running at any time?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I want to create a pool of threads for a certain task.I want to maintain a certain number of threads at any time.
How can I do that ? How can I check the number of alive threads at any time and create new threads if their count is less than the specified count ?

Comment: Perhaps your use case is a good fit for using AMQP instead of threads (chief/worker pattern), if so take a look at celery.

Comment: Something similar to python3.3's [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an existing thread pool implementation—[`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor), [`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy), or anything you find on PyPI or elsewhere—this will all be taken care of automatically.

If you want to build something yourself manually, the question doesn't really make sense. You will need to keep track of your threads, start them manually, and know when they finish, so you always know the number of alive threads.

If you want sample code to look at, [the source to `concurrent.futures`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/concurrent/futures/) is very readable, and pretty short. As you can see from a quick look, it calls `_adjust_thread_count` every time you submit a new job, and that function just checks whether `len(self._threads) < self.max_workers` and creates a new thread if needed.